# 'n' variable functions as Elements in a 'list' in linear algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

I am a beginner in Linear Algebra, I was reading about introduction to lists, It is defined in the book that list is collection of $n$ elements in a certain order of length $n$, represented as $(a,b,c......n)$. My questions are,

1.Can the elements of the list be functions of $n$ variables. An example would be $(x-y,x+2y,x+7y,...,n\text{th function})$.

2.If so then can the list represent a vector space such that it follows the properties of scalar multiplication and addition required for it to be called a vector space with a certain fixed values of
$x$ and $y$.

I request you to point out if there are any mistakes in concept of the question.

Comment: Please use MathJax to formulate mathematical terms. It is then easier for the community to read and you will more likely get a helpful answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of sets as a set whos members are *ordered lists* (or lists for short). That is, let $A$ be a non-empty set then we define
$$A^{n}:=\underbrace{A\times A\times \dots \times A}_{n}:=\{(a_{1},a_{2},\dots,a_{n}):a_{i}\in A\}.$$
Note here that nothing specifies what the elements of $A$ should be.

(Ofcourse you need not use the same set $A$ for each member in the list. You could write $A\times B$ where $A$ and $B$ are different sets.)

In order to use this set as an *underlying set* for a vector space: **you** must choose a field of scalars, define addition and scalar multiplication on $A^{n}$ and make sure the vector space axioms are satisfied.